# Functional programming issue is JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm playing around with `bind` `call` and `apply`. I am trying to update a property of an object by passing whatever is returned from one function to the method on that object.

And this updating is attached to the `window` resize event.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('someElement');

var resolveLeft = function(element) {  
  return element.offsetLeft;
};

var someObject = {
  setDefaultLeft: function(value) {
    this.defaultLeft = value;
    console.log(this.defaultLeft);
  }
};

// this works
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  someObject.setDefaultLeft(resolveLeft(el));
});

// this one doesn't
window.addEventListener('resize', someObject.setDefaultLeft.bind(someObject, resolveLeft(el)));
```

```css
#someElement {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="someElement"></div>
```

I have 2 event bindings. The first one logs out an updated value every single time the window is resized, whereas the second one only logs the initial value that was returned.

I realize that in the second case, the value was returned from `resolveLeft` already and it doesn't `revisit` (so to say) the `resolveLeft` function again. It just passes whatever was returned from the beginning.

Is there a workaround to this?

I have a feeling that currying would solve this? But not sure how to implement in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking for currying, but for [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) (together with the [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) via `bind` that you are already doing):

```
function compose(f, g) {
    return x => f(g(x));
}

var set = someObject.setDefaultLeft.bind(someObject);
window.addEventListener('resize', compose(set, resolveLeft).bind(null, el));
```